# Connecting a laptop with FHD screen to a 4k monitor

Tags: windows, display

I have a laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 720s 14") which have a screen resolution 1920 x 1080. Now I'm considering to buy a large 27" monitor and connect it to my laptop. The question is: would I be able to display my desktop at higher resolution than the laptop itself?

Comment: Supported or not, it's better to buy a 4K display. 4K is becoming the main stream spec and a monitor's lifetime is very long, you don't want your monitor to limit your usage in the future, just buy it. It'b better to buy a monitor with HDMI2.0 which supports 4K60 @ HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a higher resolution on an external display. However, according to this [spec sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/5/d/3/a/1cb461bdc56cbb8321ceaecf465826609af8.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjt1Z_44vfmAhUv1VkKHWsVBxkQFjAEegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0gR4Nl95nkEn3hyQfBOx_V), there is a difference in which external connection you use:

- 4096x2160 @ 24Hz (HDMI)
- 4096x2160 @ 60Hz (DP)

Assuming this is accurate, 24Hz is pretty low and refresh rate. You would definitely want to use the DisplayPort connector.

Comment: Can you provide the direct link instead of the Googled one? Can't find resolution spec for MX150 online, even NV link https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-mx150/specifications doesn't mention this.